# Can't Update RubyGems on Windows 10

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

Gem Version:

```
$ gem --version
2.1.2
```

Ruby Version:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x64-mingw32]
```

When I try to update Gem, I get the following error

```
$ gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `source_paths' for #<Gem::Specification:0x1595b798 rubygems-update-3.0.6>
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-3.0.6
```

Plese help me updating gem to >2.5.0.
Thanks.

Comment: This and 90% of your future issues can be solved by following: https://ubuntu.com/download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try updating it manually:

1. Go here:
   https://rubygems.org/pages/download
2. Download the zip file
3. Unzip it to some folder
4. In the terminal `cd` to this folder
5. Type `ruby setup.rb`